# Как сортировать массив по дате , чтоб сначала были старые

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
const array = [
   0: {id: 4, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2022-01-21', total: 1000}
   1: {id: 5, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2022-01-23', total: 1000}
   2: {id: 8, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2022-02-10', total: 100}
   3: {id: 9, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2022-01-28', total: 20000}
   4: {id: 11, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2022-03-08', total: 5000}
   5: {id: 12, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2021-10-27', total: 2000}
   6: {id: 15, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2022-01-01', total: 200}
   7: {id: 16, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2022-01-20', total: 300}
   8: {id: 17, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2022-01-05', total: 500}
   9: {id: 20, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2022-01-19', total: 200}
]
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Вы объект затолкали в скобки массива, это не правильно.
2. Сортировать можно так:

```js
const obj = {
    0: { id: 4, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2022-01-21', total: 1000 },
    1: { id: 5, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2022-01-23', total: 1000 },
    2: { id: 8, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2022-02-10', total: 100 },
    3: { id: 9, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2022-01-28', total: 20000 },
    4: { id: 11, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2022-03-08', total: 5000 },
    5: { id: 12, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2021-10-27', total: 2000 },
    6: { id: 15, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2022-01-01', total: 200 },
    7: { id: 16, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2022-01-20', total: 300 },
    8: { id: 17, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2022-01-05', total: 500 },
    9: { id: 20, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2022-01-19', total: 200 },
};

let res = Object.values(obj).sort((a, b) => {
    return a.date > b.date ? 1 : -1;
});
console.log('res', { ...res });
```

Результат будет следующий:

```js
res {
  '0': { id: 12, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2021-10-27', total: 2000 },
  '1': { id: 15, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2022-01-01', total: 200 },
  '2': { id: 17, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2022-01-05', total: 500 },
  '3': { id: 20, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2022-01-19', total: 200 },
  '4': { id: 16, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2022-01-20', total: 300 },
  '5': { id: 4, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2022-01-21', total: 1000 },
  '6': { id: 5, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2022-01-23', total: 1000 },
  '7': { id: 9, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2022-01-28', total: 20000 },
  '8': { id: 8, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2022-02-10', total: 100 },
  '9': { id: 11, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2022-03-08', total: 5000 }
}
```

Если на выходе нужен именно массив, замените `{ ...res }` на `res`.
Получите следующего вида:

```js
res [
  { id: 12, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2021-10-27', total: 2000 },
  { id: 15, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2022-01-01', total: 200 },
  { id: 17, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2022-01-05', total: 500 },
  { id: 20, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2022-01-19', total: 200 },
  { id: 16, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2022-01-20', total: 300 },
  { id: 4, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2022-01-21', total: 1000 },
  { id: 5, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2022-01-23', total: 1000 },
  { id: 9, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2022-01-28', total: 20000 },
  { id: 8, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2022-02-10', total: 100 },
  { id: 11, enterpriseId: 26, date: '2022-03-08', total: 5000 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, формат массива является неудачным: форма записи типа `0: {...}, 1: {...}, ...` не присуща массивам вообще: вместо этого можно просто перечислять объекты без указания на порядок.

Во-вторых, Вы забыли после каждого объекта поставить запятые, из-за чего перечисления как такого просто нет.

Ну а в-третьих, для сортировки по дате можно воспользоваться функцией, любезно взятой из [данного ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10124053). Она сначала преобразует даты всех объектов в объекты типа `Date`, а затем найдёт их разность. При этом она поменяет местами значения только в том случае, если первый объект будет иметь более позднюю дату, нежели второй, из-за чего в начало уйдут более старые объекты.

```js
const array = [
  {
    id: 4,
    enterpriseId: 26,
    date: '2022-01-21',
    total: 1000
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    enterpriseId: 26,
    date: '2022-01-23',
    total: 1000
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    enterpriseId: 26,
    date: '2022-02-10',
    total: 100
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    enterpriseId: 26,
    date: '2022-01-28',
    total: 20000
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    enterpriseId: 26,
    date: '2022-03-08',
    total: 5000
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    enterpriseId: 26,
    date: '2021-10-27',
    total: 2000
  },
  {
    id: 15,
    enterpriseId: 26,
    date: '2022-01-01',
    total: 200
  },
  {
    id: 16,
    enterpriseId: 26,
    date: '2022-01-20',
    total: 300
  },
  {
    id: 17,
    enterpriseId: 26,
    date: '2022-01-05',
    total: 500
  },
  {
    id: 20,
    enterpriseId: 26,
    date: '2022-01-19',
    total: 200
  },
]

array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date);
});

console.log(array);
```